# How do I use the new Route Handlers in nextjs 13.2?

Tags: api, next.js, request

I am trying to create an API in nextjs that gets historical stock data from the Twelve Data API. but i cant seem to figure out how to pass in parameters to retreive information for a specific stock and time range
This is my code:

```
export async function GET(request) {
  const { symbol, startDate, endDate } = request.body; // This is the problem. Dont know how to get this
  const apiKey = process.env.TWELVE_DATA_API_KEY;
  const url = `https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=${symbol}&interval=1day&start_date=${startDate}&end_date=${endDate}&apikey=${apiKey}`
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  return Response.json({data});
}
```

I am testing the API by entering this in my web browser while the app is running:
*http://localhost:3000/api/stock-info?symbol=AAPL&startDate=2020-01-01&2021-01-01*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `request.body` it should be `request.nextUrl.searchParams`.

Now, you'll get something like this: `URLSearchParams { 'num' => '123' }`.

In order to turn it into an Object you should add the following function:

```
function paramsToObject(entries) {
 const result = {}
 for(const [key, value] of entries) { // each 'entry' is a [key, value] tupple
  result[key] = value;
 }
 return result;
}
```

And then:

```
const { symbol, startDate, endDate } = paramsToObject(request.nextUrl.searchParams.entries())
```

Should work as expected. Enjoy!